# I have a transition for a label on input focus, is there a way to make the transition go backward on blur?

Tags: css, animation, sass, css-transitions

Consider the following [fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/ncz9jmdf/)

```
<div class="my-wrapper">
 <input type="text"
     placeholder="placeholder." >
 <label >Press enter to save</label>
</div>


.my-wrapper {
 input {
  width: 200px;
  height: 3em;
 }
 input:focus + label{
  right: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #D3D3D3;
 }

 label{
   line-height: 40px;
   position: absolute; 
   right: 160px; 
   -moz-transition: 0.3s right ease;
   -ms-transition: 0.3s right ease;
   -o-transition: 0.3s right ease;
   -webkit-transition: 0.3s right ease;
   transition: 0.3s right ease;
   z-index: 0;
   opacity: 0;
 }
}
```

I am seeing the forward transition on focus, I thought on blur the transition would go backwards, but I don't see it, can someone give me a hint on what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can keep this simple by using `transform` instead of absolute values

```css
.my-wrapper input {
  width: 200px;
  height: 3em;
}

.my-wrapper input:focus+label {
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
  color: #D3D3D3;
}

.my-wrapper label {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  transform: translateX(-20px);
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-wrapper">
  <input type="text" placeholder="placeholder.">
  <label>Press enter to save</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have given `transition: 0.3s right ease` which will apply only to `right` property and not for `opacity`.

Change the transition property to `transition: 0.3s all ease` and the effect fades out smoothly on blur.

[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/L87e9jcu/)